# How to select all columns instead of hard coding each one?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A PySpark `Dataframe` is in following format :

[image]

To just access the `stddev` row of columns c1,c2,c3 I use :

```py
df.describe().createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

df2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT c1 AS f1, c2 as f2, c3 as f3 from table1")
ddd = df2.rdd.map(lambda x : (float(x.f1) , float(x.f2) , float(x.f3))).zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] == 2).map(lambda x : x[0])
print type(ddd)
print type(ddd.collect())
print ddd.collect()
```

This prints :

```
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>
<type 'list'>
[(0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476)]
```

How to select the `stddev` value for all columns : c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 and generate the datatype `[(0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476....` for these selections instead of hard coding each value into the SQL string ? So the number of columns can be variable : 5, 10 columns etc...

To accomplish this for 5 columns I think to use `"SELECT c1 AS f1, c2 as f2, c3 as f3, c4 as f4, c5 as f5 from table1"` but is there a cleaner method instead of hardcoding each value in SQL and then correspondingly hard coding the value when generating the rdd : `df2.rdd.map(lambda x : (float(x.f1) , float(x.f2).....`

As my solution does not work for columns of differing lengths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use SQL aggregations directly? Either with `agg`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev

df.agg(*[stddev(c) for c in df.columns]).first()
```

where `*` is used for argument unpacking for `agg(*exprs)`, or `select`:

```py
df.select([stddev(c) for c in df.columns]).first()
```

To drop names convert `Row` to plain `tuple`:

```py
tuple(df.select(...).first())
```

or

```py
df.select(...).rdd.map(tuple).first()
```

Answer (score 15):

Selecting all columns can be quickly done using the asterisk, similar as in SQL:

```
df.select(df['*'])
```

You can also call an `alias` on a dataframe and use the `select` function:

```
df.alias("a").select("a.*")
```

Answer (score 5):

To select all columns, I decided to go this way:

df.select(df.columns).show().

Since pyspark can take a list as well as a parameter in its `select` statement, the `df.columns` which returns the list of all the columns of `df`, it should do the job. Hope it helps.

Comment: this doesn't works, TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' o
r 'create_map' function.

Answer (score 3):

Another way around with asterisk (*):

```
df.select(F.col('*'))
```

which is equivalent to `select * from table` in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what I show you as this pyspark code example:

## get all the columns from your dataframe

allColumns = yourPySparkDF.columns

## use this variable in your select

display( yourPySparkDF.select(allColumns) )